# [function.filemtime]: stat failed

Tags: php, filemtime

I have a script that reads the filemtime of zip files fine when I have the script in the same directory as the files. I can define the $dir two ways and both work.

EG:

```
$dir  = getcwd();  
//or  
$dir  = "/home/blahblah/public_html/thedirectory/";
```

However if I place the script in public_html directory I get this error

```
Warning: filemtime() [function.filemtime]: 
stat failed for TheZipFileNameWithoutTheExtension 
in /home/blahblah/public_html/listbydate.php 
on line 173
```

Any clues on why this is happening and how to fix it? I need to place the script in a different directory to where the files are stored. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use ***is_dir($dir)*** to make sure the directory you are trying to use exists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know the directory exists as $dir  = "/home/blahblah/public_html/thedirectory/"; works when I place the script in /home/blahblah/public_html/thedirectory/. It just doesn't work when I place it in /home/blahblah/public_html/.

Comment: It seems that "thedirectory" is not visible in your public_html folder. By that I mean, the public_html ignores the folder. You could move the script to "blahblah", change the directory path, then test it.